# Run Artisan Command in a route Laravel 4

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, phantomjs

I have a problem trying to run an artisan command on my routes.

This is the code:

```
Route::get('/create_preview', function() {
    Artisan::call('cartero:run-phantomjs', array('url' => 'http://stackoverflow.com/'));
});
```

My command accepts url as an argument, I'm using PhantomJS for create a screenshot from the website given.

On terminal works perfectly, but nothing happens from my browser calling the route.

Any ideas?

Comment: Done. I'm sorry about that and thank you!!!

Answer (score 2):

Having this command:

```
Usage:
 firewall:blacklist [--force] ip

Arguments:
 ip                    The IP address to be added.

Options:
 --force               Remove IP before adding it to the list.
 --help (-h)           Display this help message.
 --quiet (-q)          Do not output any message.
 --verbose (-v|vv|vvv) Increase the verbosity of messages: 1 for normal output, 2 for more verbose output and 3 for debug
 --version (-V)        Display this application version.
 --ansi                Force ANSI output.
 --no-ansi             Disable ANSI output.
 --no-interaction (-n) Do not ask any interactive question.
 --env                 The environment the command should run under.
```

This is working for me:

```
Artisan::call('firewall:blacklist', ['ip' => '10.10.10.10']);
```

You said `but nothing happens from my browser calling the route.`. That's right, nothing will show in the browser because this is a 'command line only' command and terminal printed strings, echoes, etc. are not sent to browser in Artisan::call(), not even errors.

Comment: I mean that does not work in the browser call, only on terminal

Comment: As I said, the command works in the browser, but if it's not working specifically in your command, you must provide a lot more information than just the command line which is not working, because if `url` is the correct parameter, it should work on both. But we are not seeing the internals of your `cartero:run-phantomjs` command, so it's very hard to say.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Artisan::call('cartero:run-phantomjs', array('--url' => 'http://stackoverflow.com/'));
```

Comment: --url if for options, not for arguments. By terminal I run this: `php artisan cartero:run-phantomjs http://stackoverflow.com` and works pretty well...

Answer (score 0):

This is a problem with paths in the server, here is my command:

```
public function fire()
{
  $url = $this->argument('url');
  $filename = uniqid("sc");
  $path_phantomjs = base_path() . "/phantomjs/bin/phantomjs";
  $path_js = base_path() . "/screen.js";
  $path_dest = base_path() . "/public/uploads/previews/".$filename.".png";
  return exec($path_phantomjs . " " .$path_js . " " . $url . " " .$path_dest);
}
```

Originally I wasn't using the helper base_path(), and works well on terminal but not in a browser. I added a path and works now!!!!